# Convert MKRoute to NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, mapkit

Is it possible to do this? I thought of storing it in the users Documents folder and then retrieving the data from there but that would involve having to serialize it first which would give me the data anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MKRoute object contains a [MKPolyline](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPolyline_class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/MKPolyline) object and an array of [MKRouteStep](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKRouteStep_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MKRouteStep) objects . You can access to the primitive type values in those objects and serialize them into an NSData in your own format.

After writing that NSData to a file or an sqlite database , you can always construct MKRoute from that serialized bytes .

This figure can help you understand the concept

[image: Serialization]

Comment: Except MKRoute doesn't have any initilizer ? so save tho polyline, duration, distance is ok but how to get back to the object ?

Comment: Agreed, did anyone ever get an answer this?  Taking the values of the MKRoute and streaming them out to NSData is no big deal, but how the heck do you recreate the original object, since polyline and steps are both read only you can't simple alloc/init a new MKRoute and then set the values to the newly created object... so how do you handle this?

Comment: Unless someone can explain how you can get those native types back into  an instance of the original object, this is not a complete solution.